# windows phone 7 apps in windows 8

Tags: visual-studio, windows-phone-7, windows-8

i have installed windows 8 on my laptop ,can we create windows phone 7 apps in windows 8 using Visual studio 2010 or visual studio 2012.right now i have visual studio 2012 installed in my laptop

Comment: the problem is when i try to create a new project for windows phone in visual studio 2012 it's giving me a message like "INSTALL WINDOWS PHONE 8 SDK" but windows phone 8 SDK is not yet released by microsoft, so can i install  visual studio 2010 , windows phone SDK 7.1 on windows 8 and create windows phone 7 apps

Answer (score 2):

In order to develop for Windows Phone 7 in your Windows 8 laptop, you need to install [Games for Windows Live](http://www.xbox.com/en-US/LIVE/PC/DownloadClient) **before** installing Windows Phone SDK 7.1!

The correct install workflow would be:

- Install Games for Windows Live
- Install Windows Phone 7.1 SDK
- Install Windows Phone 7.1.1 update

Note: Windows Phone 7.1 SDK is not supported on Visual Studio 2012, so unless you already have a Visual Studio 2010 edition installed, this will install Visual Studio 2010 Express and you will have to use it to make WP7 apps!

Answer (score 0):

You can still install windows phone 7.1 sdk on visual studio 2012 and develop WP7 apps for the time being.